# Convert check_load in Nagios to Zabbix

Tags: monitor, nagios, zabbix

Hi I have just built my Zabbix server and in the process of configuring some checks currently setup in Nagios.

One these checks is check_load. Can anyone explain what this check means in Nagios and how I can replicate it in Zabbix.

Answer (score 3):

In Nagios check_load monitors server load. Server load is a good indication of what your overall utilisation looks like : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)

You can view server load easily on most *nix servers using the top command. The 3 numbers at the top right show your 1, 5 and 15 minute load averages. As a brief guide the load should be less than your number of processors. So for instance if you have a 4 cpu server then I would expect your load average to sit below 4.00.

I recently did a quick load monitor in nagios script format for http://www.dataloop.io

It was done quickly and needs a fair bit of work to work across other systems. But it gives a feel for how to scrape the output of top:

```
#!/bin/bash
onemin=$(top -b -n1 | sed -n '1p' | cut -d ' ' -f 13 | sed 's/%//')
fivemin=$(top -b -n1 | sed -n '1p' | cut -d ' ' -f 14 | sed 's/%//')
fifteenmin=$(top -b -n1 | sed -n '1p' | cut -d ' ' -f 15 | sed 's/%//')

int_fifteenmin=$( printf "%.0f" $fifteenmin )

echo "OK | 1min=$onemin;;;; 5min=$fivemin;;;; 15min=$fifteenmin;;;;"

alert=10

if [ "$int_fifteenmin" -gt "$alert" ]
then
  exit 2
fi

exit 0
```

Hope this explains enough for you to create a Zabbix equivalent.

Comment: Brilliant... I will use your sample to generate a similar script for Zabbix. It may be Zabbix already has a template for this but would need to verify

Answer (score 2):

In zabbix, it is a zabbix agent built-in check. Search for system.cpu.load [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent).

As for what it measures, the already posted link to wikipedia article is a great read.